# The If statement in my for loop is acting strangely

Tags: java, arrays, validation, debugging, for-loop

My program takes user input to create a sport score table.
Its validation function prints "Invalid input" when the array "words" contains less than 4 elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { // A loop to control the Array 
    String[] words = football_list[i].split(":"); // Splits the input into 4 strings
    if (words.length != 4) { // If the length of the array elements does not equal 4 then print error message
        System.out.println("Input was not valid");
```

When I enter an incorrect input FIRST, it then makes the rest of the following scores to be deemed equally incorrect even when they are correct - here is an example of what that looks like on the text console.

> <sup>Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score</sup>
>
> <sup>Leeds : Liverpool : 2 :</sup>
>
> <sup>Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score</sup>
>
> <sup>Leeds : Liverpool : 2 : 1</sup>
>
> <sup>Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score</sup>
>
> <sup>Leeds : Liverpool : 2 : 1</sup>
>
> <sup>Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score</sup>
>
> <sup>Leeds : Liverpool : 2 : 1</sup>
>
> <sup>Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score</sup>
>
> <sup>quit</sup>
>
> <sup>Input was not valid</sup>
>
> <sup>Input was not valid</sup>
>
> <sup>Input was not valid</sup>
>
> <sup>Input was not valid</sup>
>
> <sup>Totals</sup>        
>   <sup>------------------------- Total games played: 0*</sup>
>
> <sup>END--</sup>

This is where I think the problem is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { 
    String[] words = football_list[i].split(":"); 4 strings
    if (words.length != 4) {
        System.out.println("Input was not valid");
        counter--;
        i--;
    } else {

    System.out.println(words[0].trim() + " [" + words[2].trim() + "]" + " | " + words[1].trim() + " [" + words[3].trim() + "]"); // Formats and prints the output    
        System.out.println("                 ");
        System.out.println("                 ");
        System.out.println("                 ");
        System.out.println("        Totals        ");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total games played: " +  counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really fix the indentation.

Comment: Variable name `football_list` does not conform to the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't decrement `i` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you decrement `i` and `counter` if input is invalid. And after that increase `i` in for-statement. In this case you are reading invalid row again and again while `counter > i`

Answer (score 0):

To make things more readable and less error prone, you could simply use the `length` of your array to control your loop ending, and increment `counter` (starting at 0) only when the input is valid :

```
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < football_list.length; i++) { // A loop to control the Array
            String[] words = football_list[i].split(":"); // Splits the input into 4 strings
            if (words.length != 4) { // If the length of the array elements does not equal 4 then print error message
                System.out.println("Input was not valid");

            } else {

                counter++;
                System.out.println(words[0].trim() + " [" + words[2].trim() + "]" + " | " + words[1].trim() + " ["
                        + words[3].trim() + "]"); // Formats and prints the output    

            }
        }
```